# Module Library JS Some In Header Some In Footer

Tags: 8, javascript

I have read that Drupal 8 by default loads library-defined files into the footer. My module libraries.yml file makes use of the "header: true" property as several JS files are needed to load in the header. However, now I need to add another JS file to the library, but this new file must load in the footer / just before the closing of the body tag.

How do I modify my libraries.yml file to make this JS file the only footer-loading one?

```
modulename:
  version: 1.x
  header: TRUE
  js:
    headerfile1.js: {}
    headerfile2.js: {}
    footerfile1.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.module.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it to your `*.libraries.yml` as an additional library this time **without** `header: TRUE`. And maybe better place all your JS files in a subfolder named `/js`.

```
headerlibs:
  version: VERSION
  header: TRUE
  js:
    js/headerfile1.js: {}
    js/headerfile2.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/style.module.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings

footerlibs:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    js/footerfile1.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Then attach everything as usual:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {

  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/headerlibs';
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYMODULE/footerlibs';
}
```

---

[From the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme):

> #### Asset loading order
>
> As you would expect, the order in which the files are listed is the
>   order in which they will load. By default, all JS assets are now
>   loaded in the footer. JS for critical UI elements that cannot be shown
>   unless their corresponding JS has run can be loaded in the header if
>   needed like so:
>
> ```
> js-header:
>   header: true
>   js:
>     header.js: {}
>
> js-footer:
>   js:
>     footer.js: {}
> ```
>
> Set the `header` property to `true`, to indicate that the JavaScript
>   assets in that asset library are in the 'critical path' and should be
>   loaded from the header. Any direct or indirect dependencies of
>   libraries declared in this way will also automatically load from the
>   header, you do not need to declare them individually for them to be
>   available. This is the meaning of the phrase 'critical path', once an
>   asset is declared to be in the header it is 'critical' for that asset
>   and all of its dependencies to load first.